# Is there a way to install PostgreSQL using apt-get without it running initdb automatically?

Tags: apt, 20.04, postgresql

I am trying to set up replication for PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 20.04 and for the stand-by node I just need to install the PostgreSQL-server and not run initdb. Cluster creation on the stand-by will be taken care of when I will setup replication from master.

But, when ever I am running

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
```

initdb is called and cluster is created. In other distribution such as RHEL, it is possible to not run initdb and just install the postgresql server using packages (https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/).

Is there any way to get around this? or is this just how installation works on ubuntu when installing using apt-get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: *initdb is called and cluster is created. In other distribution such as RHEL, it is possible to not run initdb and just install the postgresql server*

There are two ways to do that:

1. Either set the following option to off in **`/etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf`**:

   ```
   # Create a "main" cluster when a new postgresql-x.y server package is installed
   create_main_cluster = off
   ```

   This configuration file is part of the `postgresql-common` package, which must be installed first to have the opportunity to overwrite this option ( otherwise, it will be installed automatically as a dependency of the `postgresql-$VERSION` package).
2. Or create the directory `/etc/postgresql/$VERSION` before the `postgresql-$VERSION` package gets installed. The existence of this directory will make the post-installation script skip the creation of a default cluster.

Comment: This worked as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Debian-based Linux distributions — such as Ubuntu — will start new services as part of the post-installation scripts when installing via `apt`. This has been the default behaviour "forever". That said, you can *temporarily* disable this by *temporarily* creating [a `policy-rc.d` file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/policy-rc.d-declarative.8.html).

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (or SSH into the machine)
1. Create a `policy-rc.d` file in `/usr/sbin`:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/sbin/policy-rc.d
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Paste the following lines into the new file:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exit 101
   ```
3. Save the file and exit the editor
4. Install your application(s)

Once you are done, be sure to remove the `policy-rc.d` file, otherwise any future `apt install` operations may not succeed, such as system updates.

Comment: This worked very well. Thanks!